# Show list of all places a function is in vim

Tags: linux, vim, ctags

I found a nice feature in ctags where I type `:tj function_name` and I see a list of all places the function exists to jump to.
Is there a way to make some kind of mapping so that when my cursor is on a function name to press some key(s) and to have that list displayed instead of typing `:tj function_name` all the time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is built-in as the following commands, operating on the definition under the cursor:

- `<C-]>` like `:tag`
- `g]` like `:tselect`
- `g<C-]>` like `:tjump`

You would have found them if you had browsed around the help entry of `:h :tj`...